# Недовольство "чем-либо" или "по поводу"?

Tags: общие-вопросы, предлоги

Как правильно писать - "недовольство школами для одаренных детей" или "недовольство по поводу школ для одаренных детей"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Недовольство чем?" - вполне нормальная конструкция. "По поводу" - излишне.

Comment: Всё предложение звучит так: "В последнее время всё чаще и чаще можно слышать недовольство людей школами для одаренных детей". Нужно ли "по поводу" в данном случае?

Comment: Не вижу в том необходимости.
Нет, можно, конечно, и "по поводу" написать, но весомых для того я не вижк. Для меня, субъективно конечно, "по поводу" звучит так, что пишущий не совсем уверен, школами ли недовольны люди, чем-то ещё (а школы - просто повод) или просто ворчат по поводу и без.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, возможны оба варианта. Недовольство школами - не устраивают школы в принципе, недовольство по поводу школ - не устраивают какие-либо аспекты работы школ.

Comment: "по-поводу" звучит как-то канцелярски.